# SQL-Statement Union with helper column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help for building a SQL-statement.
The Database-Schema looks like this:
[Database-Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBjYn.png)

I did prepare the following SQL-Fiddle, which contains sample-data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/528a4e/1

**Requirement #1:**
I want to get all computers from the table "computers". The SQL-Statement would look like this:

```
SELECT ComputerID, ComputerName
FROM computers
```

**Requirement #2:**
I want to get all computers mapped to printer with PrinterID = 1. The SQL-Statement would look like this:

```
SELECT computermapping.ComputerID, computers.ComputerName
FROM computermapping
JOIN computers ON computermapping.ComputerID = computers.ComputerID
JOIN Printers ON computermapping.PrinterID = printers.PrinterID 
WHERE computermapping.PrinterID = 1
```

**Requirement #3:**
So far so good. Now I need something more complicated.
I want to join the results of booth queries to get a unique list of computers.
Those computers, which have been selected by "Requirement #2" should be marked somehow. The result shoul look like this:

[Wanted-Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIEIU.png)

I appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *all* computers, start with a `left join`:

```
SELECT c.ComputerID, c.ComputerName,
       ( cm.ComputerId IS NOT NULL) as hasPrinterFlag
FROM computers c LEFT JOIN
     computermapping cm
     ON cm.ComputerID = c.ComputerID  AND cm.PrinterID = 1 ;
```

In your case, I don't think you need the `Printers` table.  All the information appears to be in `computermapping` (unless the printer could be in the mapping table but not in the `Printers` table, which seems unlikely).

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/528a4e/5) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. Thank you very much, Gordon! :-)